# How to output arrays to text file?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I borrowed code from Powershellbros.com which displays the requested data is returned properly in the output pane, but I want to output it to a txt file.

I got the code from https://www.powershellbros.com/powershell-tip-of-the-week-get-sccm-client-version-remotely/ and want the better formatted version. The way I ended the script creates the file, but nothing is in it (1KB).

```
if ($Array) {
    return $Array 
}
& $Array Out-File -Append c:\temp\Version.txt
```

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly create a file. In the best case `$Array` is populated, meaning the code will return the array and never reach the last line. In the worst case `$Array` will be empty and the last line will throw an error (because the call operator cannot run the elements of the array. Please go find a PowerShell tutorial.

Answer (score 14):

You need to send `$Array` through the pipeline. Include the vertical bar.

```
$Array | Out-File -Append c:\temp\Version.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $array does have data, you just need to add a pipe

```
If($Array) { Return $Array }
$Array | Out-File -append c:\temp\Version.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works (verified just now):

```
foreach($line in $Array) 
{ 
  Add-Content "D:\data\filename.txt" $line
}
```